# Need help tracking down an illegal write. valgrind not noticing it

Tags: c, valgrind

ive got a C program that gets caught in a for loop that it shouldn't, running it with

`valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes a.out`

doesnt return anything even up until the program gets caught. is there a way to change the settings of valgrind to help me find the <strike>leak</strike>? as many have pointed out, it wouldnt be considered a leak, apologies

thanks in advance

here is the loop in question

```
int clockstate=0;
int clocklength=0;
int datalength=0;
int datastate=0;
int dataloc = 9;

((((some other code that i don't think is important to this part))))

int dataerr[13] = {0};
int clockerr[13] = {0};     // assumes that spill does not change within an event.
int spill=0;
int k = 0;

spill = Getspill(d+4*255+1);                // get spill bit from around the middle
//printf("got spill: %d \n", spill);            // third breakpoint
for( k = 0; k < 512; k++)
{
    // Discardheader(d);      // doesnt actually do anything, since it's a header.f
    int databit = Getexpecteddata(d+4*k+1);
    printf("%d ",k);
    int transmitted = Datasample(&datastate, &datalength, d+4*k+2,dataerr,dataloc, databit);
    printf("%d ",k);
    Clocksample(&clockstate, &clocklength, d+4*k+3,clockerr, transmitted); 
    printf("%d \n",k);
    // assuming only one error per event (implying the possibility of multi-error "errors"
    // we construct the final error at the very end of the (outside this loop)


}
```

and the loop repeats after printing

254 254 254

255 255 255

256 256 1      <- this is the problem

2 2 2

3 3 3

edit** so i've tracked down where it is happening, and at one point in

`void Clocksample (int* state, int* length, char *d, int *type, int transbit);`

i have code that says `*length = 1;` so it seems that this command is somehow writing onto `int k`. my question now is, how did this happen, why isnt it changing `length` back to one like i want, and how do i fix it. if you want, i can post the whole code to  `Clocksample`

Comment: Getting stuck in a loop and having a memory leak are two different issues.

Comment: well it's a for loop and i've made very sure not to alter the index inside the loop, is there another way to get stuck in one?

Comment: Can you post the suspected portion of the code, if possible?

Comment: what is the type of `k`?

Comment: its declared as `int k = 0` a couple lines above the loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [need help finding why a for loop's counter variable is being altered by a function inside the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677433/need-help-finding-why-a-for-loops-counter-variable-is-being-altered-by-a-functi)

Comment: You've given us even less information than the last time you asked this question.

Comment: ah, last time it was a memory error that i thought i fixed, but perhaps i am wrong, youre right. i didnt even think the two would be related. sorry. should i delete this or something?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to last time, something in one of those functions, `Clocksample()` this time, is writing to memory that doesn't belong to the data/arrays that the function should be using. Most likely an out of bounds array write. Note: this is not a memory leak, which is allocating then losing track of memory blocks that should be freed.

Set a breakpoint at the call to `Clocksample()` for when `k` is 256.  Then step into `Clocksample()`, keeping a watch on `k` (or the memory used by `k`). You can probably also just set a hardware memory write breakpoint on the memory allocated to `k`. How you do any of this depends on the debugger you're using.

Now single-step (or just run to the return of `Clocksample()` if you have a hardware breakpoint set) and when `k` changes, you'll have the culprit.

Comment: shouldnt valgrind catch that sort of thing though? under the category of illegal read write error?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with valgrind, but I'm sure there are some bad pointer manipulations that even it can't track.

Comment: thanks, i was having trouble because i didn't know how to use my debugger properly and working my way around it removed the error somehow. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that Valgrind is *exceedingly* weak when it comes to detecting **stack** buffer overflows (which is what appears to be happening here).

[Google address-sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) is much better at detecting stack overflows, and I suggest you try it instead.

Answer (score 1):

So your debugging output indicates that `k` is being changed during the call to your function `Clocksample`.  I see that you are passing the addresses of at least two variables, `&clockstate` and `&clocklength` into that call.  It seems quite likely to me that you have an array overrun or some other wild pointer in `Clocksample` that ends up overwriting the memory location where `k` is stored.

It might be possible to narrow down the bug if you post the code where `k` is declared (and whatever other variables are declared nearby in the same scope).  For example if `clocklength` is declared right before `k` then you probably have a bug in using the pointer value `&clocklength` that leads to writing past the end of `clocklength` and corrupting `k`.  But it's hard to know for sure without having the actual layout of variables you're using.

valgrind doesn't catch this because if, say, `clocklength` and `k` are right next to each other on the stack, valgrind can't tell if you have a perfectly valid access to `k` or a buggy access past the end of `clocklength`, since all it checks is what memory you actually access.

Comment: i declare 


    `int clockerr[13]= {0};`
    `int spill = 0;`
    `int k = 0;`

so i'll give that a try, thanks a lot!

Comment: i would be able to tell if this was the case by changing where i declare `k`, right?

Comment: I changed where i declared k and it moved the error to Datasample instead, so it seems you are spot on. i then moved it even higher, and the error didnt show up anymore. it is obviously still there though.